# Closing a modal using usestate hook in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've asked this problem yesterday and got an answer that I understood and tried to implement.  I'm having problems accessing the state variable in my modal after I call it in the parent component.

Here is the state variable I've setup:

```
const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
```

Here is how I call that modal in my parent component and here is my modal component and how I use that `closeModal` function in my modal props:

```
export const Modal = (props) => {
  const test = props.person.name;
  const fname = props.person.fname;
  const patientid = props.person.patientid;
  //this function should be in the props array, but its not there.
  const setshow = props.closeModal;
  
  const url = "https://testcf-boisterous-ardvark-pc.mybluemix.net/test/addAppointment?pid=999998&date=${state.date}&starttime=${state.stime}:00&timecost=00:09:00&name=${state.fname},${state.lname}&reason=${state.type}";
  
  useEffect(async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios(url);
      const data = response.data;
      console.log("testing our useeffect");
      console.log(data);
    }
    catch(error) { 
      console.log(error.response);
    }
  }, []);

  if (!props.show) {
    return null
  }
  
  const fetchData = async () => {
    //console.log("calling fetchData");
    try {
      const response = await axios(url);
      const data = response.data;
      console.log(data);
    }
    catch(error) { 
      console.log(error.response);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="modal" onClick={props.onClose}>
      <div className="background" onClick={e =>e.stopPropagation()}>
        <div>
          <h4 className="margin-bottom">Saving to Master</h4>
          <h4 className="margin-top">Confirming Your Booking</h4>
          <img src={logo} alt="logo image" />
          <h2 class="reduce-text">Save and Submit Timeslot</h2>
          <h4>for <span class="bold underline">{test}</span></h4>
          <div>
            <h5>{patientid}</h5>
            <img src={boxes} alt="Two Double Boxes" />
          </div>
        </div>
      <div className="modal-footer">
        <button className="btn-close"  onClick={props.onClose}>Cancel</button>
        <button className="btn-submit" onClick={props.onClose}>Confirm</button>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>\
  )
};

export default Modal;
```

I use the modal like this:\

```
<Modal 
  closeModal={setshow}
  person={{ 
    name: state.fname, 
    imageId: '1bX5QH6',
    notificationTitle: 'Regular Appointment',
    time: state.stime,
    adate: state.date,
    timecost: state.timecost,
    reason: state.type,
    patientid: '999999'
  }}
/>
```

Comment: How do you know that you don't access?

Comment: could you add the entire modal component

Comment: Konrad -- i don't have it in my intellisence!  But I have the person array in there, so Im not 100% sure why i don't have the state function.

Comment: monim -- i've edited the post to contain the whole modal.js compoent

Comment: Show how you use this component

Comment: Konrad -- posted

Answer (score 0):

You're setting state wrong, like Amin pointed out in their answer.

You want to pass a *function* to your `Modal` component that the `Modal` will later *invoke* when it wants to close, effectively bubbling the state to the parent component. You'll also pass the current value of `show` to the Modal, so it knows if it should display or not.

This is how you'll pass it to your `Modal`:

```
<Modal 
   closeModal={() => setshow(false)}
   show={show}
   ...
/>
```

Then, within your modal, do *not* have `const setshow = props.closeModal`, you don't need that.

Within your modal component, you can return early if `!props.show`, just like you're doing:

```
// effectively depends on the parent's state, since it's passed down
if (!props.show) {
    return null
}
```

And then, to solve your issue, simply:

```
onClick={props.closeModal}
// which is equivalent to
onClick={() => props.onClose()}
```

So it will call the function that was passed to it, which (in this case) will update the state in the parent. This is the pattern all Modal libraries I've used tend to use. It's powerful because you can pass it more complicated functions into `closeModal` when calling your modal, allowing you to easily take other actions when a modal is closed besides just updating your show state.

That will work now, since `props.closeModal`

Answer (score -1):

"const setshow = props.closeModal" That's not the right way to update a state.

**Try** setShow(props.closeModal).

Comment: thanks, i managed to figure it out with that comment.  Very much appreciated.